# iOS 7 upgrade custom keyboard background issue

Tags: ios7, uikeyboard

I am using a custom keyboard in my app. This was working really well, but on upgrading to iOS 7 there is a background displayed behind my custom keyboard in the shape of the default keyboard - none of the keyboard keys of the default keyboard are displayed, just a transparent pale box in the shape of the default keyboard. Has anyone else had the same issue or know of a way to resolve this?

The code i am using to hide the default keyboard is:

```
id keyboardImpl = [objc_getClass("UIKeyboardImpl") sharedInstance];
[keyboardImpl setAlpha:0.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that to hide a UIKeyboard because it relies on private classes what can change in any OS release without warning

Take a look at the inputView property on UITextField: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView